# Canonical transformations in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator, canonical-conjugation

Heisenberg's famous commutator of a pair of conjugated canonical variables is formulated for position and conjugated momentum

$$[q,p] = i\hbar.$$

Intuitively I would guess that it would also work other pairs of conjugated variables, in particular those obtained by canonical transformation from $(q,p)$. However, actually I have never seen a canonical transformation in Quantum Mechanics (well, may be the pair of an annihilation and creation operators are result of canonical transformation ... actually I never checked that). In particular I would be interested if in Quantum Mechanics angle-action variables are used, which can be obtained from the $(q,p)$-pair by a canonical transformation. As the action plays a promiment role in Quantum Mechanics (for instance in the path integral) I would expect the appearance of angle-action variables in Quantum Mechanics, but actually I have never seen it.

What's all about -- are canonical transformations a tool used in QM or is it limited only to classical physics? Are angle-action variables are of interest and use in QM?

Comment: See my answer to [Can we theoretically balance a perfectly symmetrical pencil on its one-atom tip?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175985/37364)

Comment: Related: [Why don't we use Hamilton-Jacobi method in QM?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103981/2451)

Comment: The (quantum) isomorphisms of the Heisenberg algebra are broader than the (classical) ones of the Poisson Bracket algebra, but they are [all-important and useful](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9503080) in [quantum theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9305054). Should have been part of your course.

Comment: An easy starting point is [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.35.1289) one.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you for the information and the reference. Unfortunately I lost easy access to most scientific papers.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find an e-print version of the last PRD paper. I found [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9905002), instead...

Comment: @Comas Zachos The arxiv paper looks very interesting. Thank you very much!

Comment: If $q'=UqU^{\dagger}$ and for $p'$ then $[q',p']=U[q,p]U^{\dagger}=i=[q,p]$, thus conjugation of operators by unitary transformations preserves the commutator (analog of preserving the PB under a canonical transformation = CT) and so are the analogue of CT. A CT can be written via P.B.'s and a generator $Q$ as $q'=q+\epsilon \frac{\partial Q}{\partial p}+..=q+\{q,\epsilon Q\}+..=e^{ \{ \  , \epsilon Q\}} q$. If $U = e^{i Q}$ then $q' = UqU^{\dagger}=e^{iQ}qe^{-iQ} = e^{-i[ \ , Q]}q$, and from $e^{(-i) i \{ \  ,\epsilon Q\}}\to e^{-i [ \  , \epsilon Q ]}$ you see the link explicitly.

Comment: But note the classical and quantum groups of canonical transformations [*cannot* be isomorphic!](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/soysoy/VanHove1951.pdf) because the PB and commutator algebras cannot be isomorphic: the Groenewold-VanHove theorem.